# how to change where public ip redirects

Tags: magento-1.8, url, url-rewrite

I am new to Magento and I am trying to change the address where my public ip directs, but honestly do not quite know how to do it. So if anyone could lend a hand it would be much appreciated.

I have an ip, let´s say `http://12.34.456.89/` and when I navigate to it from browser I end up in the first magento page (Concratulations You are now running Bitnami Magento 1.9.0.1-0 virtual appliance. blaa, blaa), but I would need it redirect into `http://12.34.456.89/magento/` where the actual store resides.

How can I make the the redirection so, that upon entering `http://12.34.456.89/` on the browser, user will end up on `http://12.34.456.89/magento` ?

Many thanks for helping a newbie out.

Comment: you mean on your local system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are asking for your local system, for Windown go to `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc` and edit `hosts` file in `Notepad`. You need to run the Notepad as **Administrator**.

In Ubuntu the path is `/etc/hosts`, edit this file in your editor like VIM as a root so use the command `sudo vim /etc/hosts`

Both OS will require to add a line in the file as

```
12.34.456.89 12.34.456.89/magento
```

Note a **space** between both. whatever you write before space is request and whatever is after the space is the target.
save the file and try the request part. I hope it will redirect to the target.

Comment: Sorry, no I am asking for Ubuntu server.

Comment: in Ubuntu the path is /etc/hosts

Comment: @MTM. Are you sure that it will work by editing the hosts? I think you need to change the document root, or you need an htaccess redirect, but not sure...that's why I'm asking.

Comment: @Marius, he asked for Ubuntu server, and i guess server uses host file

Comment: @Marius, you may be right, i am removing my answer. :)

Comment: @MTM. I guess you are right. +1 from me then.

Answer (score 1):

if you are using ubuntu server... with

> > nignx - goto nginx default.conf and edit the line or a similar method for .htaccess in apache

```
 server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  yourname.com or ip address;



    location / {
```

> > ```
> >       root   /usr/share/nginx/html; # change the root directory to magento directory
> >         index  index.php index.html index.htm;
> >     }
> > ```

or you can simply create index.php file in you current directory and use redirect method...

```
<?php header('location:magento/'); ?>
```

But it is not the recommended way